# Using Scanner class withing java to avoid seeing quotes

Tags: java, excel, java.util.scanner

This is sample of raw data I've been given. I need to put paticular parts in a excel spreadsheets. Before I even start on that I would like to parse this info to be easily manage when putting in spreadsheets. one of the needed informations is vector number. ex. "vector number" "1701".  For the life of me I can't seem to use the scanner class in such a way I can retrieve this info because its in double quotes. That is the numbers in the quotes and keep them as an int value. Thanks in advance everyone

-2-2015  0:16 PM  -  Report for Voice System name: Commercial  -  l usa e 1797747

""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"Announcement"  ""  ""  ""  ""
"Vector"    "Vector Number" "1701"  "Step"  "8"

9-2-2015  0:16 PM  -  Data Export

9-2-2015  0:16 PM  -  Report for Voice System name: Commercial  -  l usa e 1797789

""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"Announcement"  ""  ""  ""  ""
"Vector"    "Vector Number" "1701"  "Step"  "26"

9-2-2015  0:16 PM  -  Data Export

9-2-2015  0:16 PM  -  Report for Voice System name: Commercial  -  l usa e 1797745

""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"Announcement"  ""  ""  ""  ""
"Vector"    "Vector Number" "1701"  "Step"  "3"

9-2-2015  0:16 PM  -  Data Export

Answer (score 1):

There might be away to exlude the quotes, but, you can use `Scanner`s regular expression capabilities to change the way in which it works, for example

```
String text = "\"\" \"\" \"\" \"\" \"\" \"Announcement\" \"\" \"\" \"\" \"\" \"Vector\" \"Vector Number\" \"1701\" \"Step\" \"8\"";

String pattern = "([\"'])(?:(?=(\\\\?))\\2.)*?\\1";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);
while (scanner.hasNext(pattern)) {
    System.out.println(scanner.next(pattern));
}
```

Which outputs something like...

```
""
""
""
""
""
"Announcement"
""
""
""
""
"Vector"
```

It would be a simple thing to just use `String#replaceAll` to remove the quotes from each result

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you use a CSV library like https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/.  Which allows you to change the delimiter.

There are [many other libraries to choose from](https://github.com/robert-bor/CSVeed/wiki/Comparison-of-Java-CSV-libraries).

If this is real data, you may run into a lot of corner cases.  It may be time consuming to deal with them all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the data is formatted like this, you could first get an entire line of data with Scanner.nextLine(), and then store that in a string. Next you could use String.indexOf() to get the number you want. For example:
`String input = yourScanner.nextLine();
int pos = input.indexOf("Vector Number");
int result = String.substring(pos + 16, pos +20);`
This is is a very crude implementation of what you want, but you get the idea.
Good Luck!